# Offline help files for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, chm

Is there any offline help files for CodeIgniter framework. For reading on train or something like that.

Comment: There are applications that store web pages for offline reading - Google e.g. `offline reader <name of your OS>`. You can also print to a PDF with a PDF printer driver like PDFCreator: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/. (either way, this is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow)

Comment: yap Codeignitor itself have library . you can read this .

Comment: In the CI folder there is a `user_guide` folder. It has HTML files which you can view offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your code igniter folder, navigate to the user_guide folder. Once there you can open the index.html for full access to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I've never noticed that there is documentation in release.